# Recycler View not updating and displaying anything

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a simple note app in which I'm showing the content in recycler view from firestore. Something is wrong in the code its not displaying the content in the recylerview(though I'm getting a new item each time I add a new note). Also it not updated as soon as I add a new note, its updated once I destroy the app.

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    ArrayList<Model> models;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        models = new ArrayList<>();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, models);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        firebaseFirestore.collection("my_notes_collection").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                            for(DocumentSnapshot d : list){
                                Model model = d.toObject(Model.class);
                                models.add(model);
                            }
                            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to get the data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> addData());
    }

    private void addData() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataAdd.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Model> models;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models){
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.time_text.setText(models.get(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()).getText());
        holder.string_text.setText(models.get(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()).getNotes());
        holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotesDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return models.size(); }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView string_text, time_text;
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            string_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            time_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeshow);
            constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true) and linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); will display the recyclerview in the reverse order. So check if new items are added to the top instead of the bottom of the list.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMam

Answer (score 0):

By looks of it, the reason its not updating RV is because we are not asking the code to do that, yet.

So listen for when `DataAdd` activity has completed its addition task by using `startActivityForResult()` please see [an example here](https://mobikul.com/android-start-activity-for-result/)

Then when we know add was successful, we get a callback in,  `onActivityResult()` we then reload list from Firebase

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("my_notes_collection").get()
 ...
```

again such that the list is updated and dataset is notified..

Comment: Hi @Sum did the approach work out for you ?